# React Native save a http Image to Android camera roll

Tags: javascript, react-native, camera-roll

Here are some images from websites and I want to save them to Android camera roll.

I found out that React Native has an function `CameraRoll.saveImageWithTag` which could save certain image into the camera roll, but the param `tag` should be a local URI, such as `"file:///sdcard/img.png"`. So how to save the image in Android React Native if the image source was not local?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the file first. You can use [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) to do that

Or, if you are using Expo you can use [`FileSystem.downloadAsync`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem#expofilesystemdownloadasyncuri-fileuri-options).

Those will give you a local Uri to use with `CameraRoll.save...` (I think it has a different name now)